# Linear Regression with Time Series Data

Tags: regression, time-series, least-squares, linear

I am in the process of completing an applied econometrics project and want to find the effects of my chosen independent variables (fertility, gender wage gap, years of schooling, etc) on my dependent variable (female labour participation rate).

I have 30 annual observations for each variable.

At first, I tried to find if a cointegrating relationship existed but there is none.

Would it be suitable to continue my project using OLS regression?

In addition to checking for autocorrelation, what else should I look out for?

Comment: Endogeneity could be a problem...

Answer (score 2):

OLS assumes that your dependent variable is independent across your observations. In other words, if you perform OLS you're assuming female labour participation at year 1 is independent from year 2. This assumption is likely wrong when you're dealing with time series data like this.

When you have dependence in your dependent variables, this is called autocorrelation. There are sets of models called autoregressive models that can handle this. These models will outperform OLS when you have autocorrelation.

Comment: I don't think the first sentence is correct. Independence is usually assumed for error terms, not the dependent variable. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares#Classical_linear_regression_model) (scroll down to "Time series model") might not be the most reliable source when it comes to statistics, but it does not have any assumptions on the dependent variable besides stationarity and ergodicity.

Comment: The error terms being independent is equivalent to the DV being independent when the IV are treated as fixed.

Comment: The caveat *when the IV are treated as fixed* was worth mentioning. Also, IV here stands for *independent variables*, right? (I am more used to seeing IV in the context of *instrumental variables*.)

Comment: IMO fixed independent variables is a pipe dream infesting stats books. All estimation procedures depend on how the samples are distributed. What's your opinion @Richard ?

Comment: @CagdasOzgenc, I guess I have to agree. I wish I knew econometrics better to really grasp how serious the problem is in practice.